# How to get the value of the array inside a json

Tags: php, arrays, json, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

Hi I am a newbie to codeigniter. I am building a web service using codeIgniter. I have a json format which is given below

```
        {

        "pk_mobilenumber": 9711954265,
        "first_name": "utpal",
        "last_name":"sharma",
        "password":"Spaneos",
        "email_address":"utpalsharma@spaneos.com",
        "address":[
    {
        "area": "abc",
        "zipcode": "12344"
 }
    ]
        }
```

What i want to to get the value of the address array individually. I have got the remaining value as it is a post method. I have my post method below which gives me all the value other than address array please help me in getting the address array values.

```
function addUser_post(){
        $pk_mobilenumber = $this->post('pk_mobilenumber');
        $first_name = $this->post('first_name');
        $last_name = $this->post('last_name');
        $password = $this->post('password');

        //$city = $this->address->post('city');
        $address[] = $this->post('address');
        $area=$this->post("address['area']");
        //$zipcode=$this->post('zipcode');
        //$country=$this->address->post('country');
        $email_address = $this->post('email_address');

        //$data = json_decode($address);

        //echo $address;
        //echo $data['area'];
        //echo $zipcode;

        //$address = $this->post('address',"[]");

    //  $address1 = explode(",", $address);

        //echo $address1;

        echo $area;
        //echo $zipcode;

        $this->load->model('register_model');
        //echo "register";
        $data = $this->register_model->addUser($pk_mobilenumber,$first_name,$last_name,$password,$email_address);

        if($data){
        $this->response("Registration is successful", 201);
        }else{
            $this->response("User already exists. Please try with different Mobile number", 400);
        }

    }
```

Comment: what about $this->post("address")->area ??

Comment: I suppose it may work $this->post("address")->("area");

Comment: @Khushboo says trying fetch property of non object

Comment: Replace $address[] = $this->post('address');  $area=$this->post("address['area']");   with  $address= $this->post('address');  $area=$address[0]['area'];

Comment: No its not work @PHPWeblineindia

Comment: Could you pls track and provide $this->post('address'); return value?

Comment: @PHPWeblineindia it gave me `Array to string conversion` and even said as `undefined variable: area` when i gave `echo $address`

Comment: print using "print_r" like print_r($this->post('address'));.  Looks like you are printing with "echo" so you are getting Array to string conversion error

Comment: Yes @PHPWeblineindia i am getting the details

Comment: but how to get the value as i have to added it to the DB also as an individual table relating to the parent primary key as mobile number @PHPWeblineindia

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70850/discussion-between-php-weblineindia-and-naveen).